# Extra parameters added to webmethods

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection, proxy

I'm reading some `MethodInfo` from a proxy generated from a wsdl.

One of the methods has three (`int`) parameters and a `int` return type, but when I explore the `ParameterInfo[]` I actually see eight parameters:

- `Int32`,
- `Boolean`,
- `Int32`,
- `Boolean`,
- `Int32`,
- `Boolean`,
- `Int32&`,
- `Boolean&`

Where do these extra parameters originate?

**UPDATE**

To elaborate a bit more, the code in the generated proxy looks as following:

```
  /// <remarks/>
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/IInleerAppService/AddThreeNumbers", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public void AddThreeNumbers(int one, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] bool oneSpecified, int two, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] bool twoSpecified, int three, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] bool threeSpecified, out int AddThreeNumbersResult, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()] out bool AddThreeNumbersResultSpecified) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("AddThreeNumbers", new object[] {
                one,
                oneSpecified,
                two,
                twoSpecified,
                three,
                threeSpecified});
    AddThreeNumbersResult = ((int)(results[0]));
    AddThreeNumbersResultSpecified = ((bool)(results[1]));
}
```

Why is this?

UPDATE

If you're bugged by this, as I am, you cane easily avoid displaying those extra parameters by simply applying the following snippet of code:

```
if (!parameterInfo[i].Name.EndsWith("Specified") && !parameterInfo[i].IsRetval && !parameterInfo[i].Name.EndsWith("Result"))
{
    // magic
}
```

Comment: What did you use to get the MethodInfo? are you sure this is the same method? what, for example, is the method name here? basically: more context please

Comment: Basically I just generated a proxy assembly in code and read it via reflection. I wrote the webservice myself as well, it really is the same method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently found this out for myself. In some cases it has todo with `minoccurs=0` in the XSD. The WCF proxy class doesn't use nullable types, so it's not possible for the XmlSerializer to determine whether you want or don't want to send a certain field.

You can set `one`, but it won't be sent. You also have to set `oneSpecified` to `true` to make the serializer serialize the value of `one` and send it.

Some more info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2010/03/22/how-to-get-minoccurs-0-in-the-schema-for-xmlserializer-struct-members.aspx).

Comment: I ran into similar issues myself when I moved from VS 2008 to VS 2010.  Great answer CodeCaster!